# Python importing error from the same directory

Tags: python

I understand that this post will definitely be marked as a duplicate, but I've already searched online and nothing seems to work in my case.

I have the following two files with `main.py` trying to import `myClass` from `myFile.py`. Both `main.py` and `myClass.py` are in the exact same directory with nothing else.

I'm using python 3.6 in VS Code.

**Directory**

```
someDirectory\
 - myFile.py
 - main.py
```

**myFile.py**

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val 
    def getVal(self):
        return self.val
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".")

from myFile import myClass

newClass = myClass(5)
val = newClass.getVal()

print(val)
```

This keeps returning the error saying that `ImportError: cannot import name 'myClass'`

I'm honestly quite new to python and there must be a very silly error that I've made. I tried my best to look online but nothing helped in this case. I'd appreciate any help possible.

**Edit:** The problem is resolved. I'm not sure how, but the issue disappeared after I added a `.` before `myFile`, ran it, and then removed it. I didn't change anything else at all.

Comment: Did you check your working directory? Most probably it is different than where your files are.

Comment: Make sure to describe how you run your file (and in what directory you are when you run it)

Comment: This should work without any problem. You must be making a mistake that you are overlooking. The code above worked without any problem on my machine. If you typed it instead of pasting it from your files, you should try copying the same code to your files and test it again.

Comment: Yes, I ran my file in `main.py`. In the VS Code terminal, it shows that the file is `File "d:/Programming/Python/Workspace/testDirectory/main.py"`. I'll update the post with this included in more detail

Answer (score 0):

Idk why dont let u but there was an error there:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = val 
    def getVal(self):
        return self.val
```

U need val as parameter, so:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val 
    def getVal(self):
        return self.val
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a dot before myFile

```
from .myFile import myClass
```

Comment: After doing `.myFile`, I got the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.myFile'; '__main__' is not a package`. Any clues on what this refers to?